# Push on every field of an array PHP

Tags: php

In n array which every element is an associative array,on every child array I want to push the same field with this function,but it doesn't work.

```
function setButton($data){
    foreach ($data as $field) {
        $field['button'] = '<input data-id="'.$field['id'].'" type="submit">';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: you can't because same indexes will replace the new value to older one. Alternate is:-  `$i =0; foreach ($data as $field) {
        $field[$i]['button'] = '<input data-id="'.$field['id'].'" type="submit">';$i++;
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only editing the `$field` elements inside your foreach, but aren't actually editing your original `$data` array.

A `foreach` loop works by copying each value into a temporary variable.

If you want to edit the original array, you have two solutions :

Either pass the value with a reference, using & :

```
foreach ($data as &$field) {
    $field['button'] = '<input data-id="'.$field['id'].'" type="submit">';
}
```

Or use the `$key=>$value` notation and edit the original array :

```
foreach ($data as $key => $field) {
    $data[$key]['button'] = '<input data-id="'.$field['id'].'" type="submit">';
}
```

Comment: oh i got my code loophole. deleted my answer and  +1 to you

Answer (score 0):

As your key is not dynamic. So, its overriding  every time.

```
function setButton($data){
    foreach ($data as $field) {
        $field[]['button'] = '<input data-id="'.$field['id'].'" type="submit">';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Naincy I am not down-voter but this is nowhere solution of the question. Read:- `on every child array I want to push the same field with this function`? Correct answer given by Roberto