# Get < instead &lt

Tags: php

I get this code

```
<td class="button">&lt;input class="btn btn-default csv" type="submit"&gt;</td>
```

instead

```
<td class="button"><input class="btn btn-default csv" type="submit">;</td>
```

with  this code on php

```
$field['button'] = '<input class="btn btn-default csv" type="submit">';
```

I need to get the < and > in order to see the button

Comment: How do you render the string in your html?

Comment: are you sure you're not using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) somewhere?

Comment: And how do you process the $field["button"] to show the button itself?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is html escaping http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php.

It should be perfectly fine if you just use this:

```
<td class="button">
<?php echo $field["button"];?>
</td>
```

Comment: [I said that earlier....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139120/get-instead-lt#comment71444426_42139120) but they're not responding.

Comment: and feel it has something to do with their other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42135053/1415724 that hasn't been marked as solved; so they're not telling us the full story here.